# Dynamic values in JWT token

Tags: authentication, jwt

I have a matchmaking server that I've wanted to use for a game I'm making in the future.

My issue lies with the JWT token.

How do I go about storing dynamic values in JWT tokens efficiently? I prefer not to break the stateless part of JWT or quit JWT tokens entirely, but I want to store dynamic parts like the players' wins/losses or stats in general which adjust every game they play.

I use PyJWT, if that helps.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem? What prevents you from generating short-lived JWT with your "dynamic" data?

Comment: I'm also not sure that this isn't a pure programming question, since you are looking for "efficiency".

Comment: I don't see a security question here. For me the use case is about storing some dynamic data in the JWT, without these data being security relevant.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong "solution" for your issue. Maybe you should use client-side storage for noncritical data that doesn't need to be shared (like UI settings), use server-side storage for all the other data, and use JWT only for user identification and authentication. That means maybe more computation server-side that what you'd like, but since you should never trust client-side data, you'd have to check the coherence and validity of user-generated data anyway.

Comment: Woah, alot to reply to here.
1- The data can change at anytime, and i would much prefer this change almost instantly.
2- I guess you could say that..
3- The fundamental part of this question is JWTs and how to store changing data in them like permissions, etc, that could change and need to apply fast, I will switch this to a different place if you still see it too unrelated to Information Security.
4- I don't understand this, are you saying i should look it up on the server? wouldn't this break JWTs idea of being stateless?

Comment: But i like @Shireheart s answer, could you please post it as an answer so i could mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store dynamic values as "claims" or properties bound into the token. When your user data changes simply issue a new token with new claims. Whatever SDK your using for JWT should have functions adding claims to your tokens.

Comment: I guess i could use something like version numbers to update JWT tokens.. thanks!!